# How to pass the parameters to the POST API using Alamofire in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a post request with a body in swift using Alamofire.

```
 Add Paramets to chat 
 ["user_id": 10, "message_body": {
  MessageBody = "Test the game ";
"chatlist_id" = 32;
"from_user_id" = 21;
"from_user_image" = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/streetsmartb2/sai/IMG_0523.JPG";
"from_user_name" = Abhi;
"last_message_time" = 1495276754453;
"to_user_id" = 10;
"to_user_image" = nil;
"to_user_name" = saikumar;
```

}]
above two parameters passing through Alaomfire

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: getParametersForChat() ,  headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            print("chat notitification response \(response)")
```

Here my response is

```
chat notitification response FAILURE: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error Code=-6006 "JSON could not be serialized. Input data was nil or zero length." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=JSON could not be serialized. Input data was nil or zero length.}
```

please solution above issue it is my side problem (passing wrong way or )or php side problem

Comment: what are you passing in headers ?

Comment: Make you method `getParametersForChat()` return type of NSDictionary or directly put your dictionary in parameters

Comment: @GRamiReddy the error code `-6006` representative failure to resolve JSON.

Comment: the problem is from your side see my example

Answer (score 0):

The problem is definitely your side and not the PHP, because you are not passing valid JSON.

Square braces "[]" indicate an array, but it looks like your top level should be an object

http://www.elated.com/articles/json-basics/

Answer (score 0):

When your using Alamofire then it already has a parameter called parameters

```
let params: Parameters = ["user_id":10,
                          "message_body" : [
                              "chatlist_id" = 32,
                              "from_user_id" = 21,
                              "from_user_image" =     "https://s3.amazonaws.com/streetsmartb2/sai/IMG_0523.JPG",
                              "from_user_name" = Abhi,
                              "last_message_time" = 1495276754453,
                              "to_user_id" = 10
                              "to_user_image" = nil,
                              "to_user_name" = saikumar,
                           ]
                         ]
```

now pass in this params that we have created

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: params ,  headers: headers)
    .responseJSON { (response) in
        print("chat notitification response \(response)")
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue that I can see in your code is with your JSON that you are trying to create. It's not in proper format. The issues I can see are stated below:

1. In IOS to create a JSON you can not use curly braces "{}".
2. After each key value pair there should be a comma.
3. You cannot use semi collon ";" in your JSON.

I'll suggest you to first see some tutorials to understand the format of JSON creation/parsing. Because JSON is something that you'll be using again and again in App Development. So, your concepts should be clear on this.